# Disabling multiple simultaenous ssh sessions

Tags: server

Can someone please show me how to disable multiple simultaneous ssh sessions for an account on an Ubuntu 10.04 server. The setup currently in place is that every account has ssh access to the server.

The response given on the other question basically stated or showed how to  deny users or allow the user to access the server via ssh.

In the setup  I have got, all users have to have ssh access, but none of them are to have duplicate ssh sessions running at the same time from a Remote Desktop.

Comment: i had asked the "restricting ssh session..." question and that was incorrectly answered

Comment: you need to revise your original question then.  Please read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) especially: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions